# Batch script that detect Windows 10 edtition and act depending on it

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

so what id like to have is a batch script that will act depending on the Windows 10 edition the user has. So right now I do have a basic script with a `case` but it requires the user input. So I would like some help/tips on how to write that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this command can help: **FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2*" %A IN ('REG QUERY "hklm\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V ProductName^|FIND/I"REG_SZ"') DO @ECHO %C**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Windows 10 has WMIC.exe, here's a possible solution which may be of assistance to you:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set /A "SKU=OSV=0"
For /F "EOL=O Tokens=1,2 Delims=. " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 OS Where "Version>10" Get OperatingSystemSKU^, Version 2^>NUL'
) Do Set /A "SKU=%%G, OSV=%%H" 2>NUL
If Not %OSV% Equ 10 GoTo :EOF
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 "^::%SKU%:" "%~f0"') Do Set "EDN=Windows %OSV% %%H"
Echo %%EDN%% = %EDN%
Pause
GoTo :EOF
Rem Windows 10 Editions
::4:Enterprise
::27:Enterprise N
::48:Professional
::49:Professional N
::72:Enterprise Evaluation
::84:Enterprise N Evaluation
::98:Home N
::99:Home China
::100:Home single language
::101:Home
::119:TeamOS
::121:Education
::122:Education N
::123:IoT Core
::125:Enterprise LTSB
::126:Enterprise LTSB N
::129:Enterprise LTSB Evaluation
::130:Enterprise LTSB N Evaluation
::131:IoT Core Commercial
::136:Holographic
::138:Professional Single Language
::161:Professional for workstation
::162:Professional for workstation N
::164:10 Professional Education
::165:Professional Education N
::171:Enterprise G
::172:Enterprise G N
::175:Enterprise Multi-session
::188:IoT Enterprise
```